# So I built an app that's suppose to get the words per minute. How do you start a timer that's not in ContentView with SwithUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to start a timer of 60 seconds to test how many words a user can type within that minute. I started counting the characters within the TextField. But Now I need to decrement a timer so I can do the math and print out the answer to the user. I can't seem to figure out how to use the timer when it's not in the Content View struct though. Can I do that?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var userInput = ""
    @State var modalview = false
    @State var getstarted = false
    @EnvironmentObject var timerHolder : TimerHolder
    var body: some View {

        ZStack() {
            modalView(modalview: $modalview, userInput: userInput)

        }.sheet(isPresented: $modalview) {

        modalView(modalview: self.$modalview)

        }

    }

}




        struct modalView : View {
         @ObservedObject var durationTimer = TimerHolder()

          @Binding var modalview : Bool
            @State var userInput: String = ""


              var body: some View {

                VStack{

                   Button(action: {
                      self.modalview = true
                                 }) {
                                    TextField("Get Started", text:$userInput)
                                        .background(Color.gray)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .frame(width: 300, height: 250)
                                              .cornerRadius(20)

                                    Text("\(userInput.count)")


                                    Text("\(durationTimer.count) Seconds")

                    }

                  }
            }

        }

class TimerHolder : ObservableObject {
var timer : Timer!
@Published var count = 0
func start() {
    self.timer?.invalidate()
    self.count = 0
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {
        _ in
        self.count += 1
        print(self.count)
    }
}






struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView() 
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simples one, as you hold it as property, is to start in `.onAppear`... (supposing, of course, that you pass it in `ContentView().environmentObject(TimerHolder())` on `ContentView` creation)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var userInput = ""
    @State var modalview = false
    @State var getstarted = false
    @EnvironmentObject var timerHolder : TimerHolder
    var body: some View {

        ZStack() {
            modalView(modalview: $modalview, userInput: userInput)
        }.sheet(isPresented: $modalview) {
           modalView(modalview: self.$modalview)
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.timerHolder.start()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you've done with the timer and that makes so much sense! I'm not sure what updating the ContentView means, though?

Comment: Saying "updating ContentView" to which part / line do you refer?

Comment: The part where you said, ContentView().environmentObject(TimerHolder())

Comment: This is a required injecting of environment object for making `@EnvironmentObject var timerHolder : TimerHolder` work, otherwise you get run-time crash.

Comment: I did that part but I'm getting a runtime error. It's saying No ObservableObject of type TimerHolder found.

Comment: For Preview you have to do this in `ContentView_Previews`, for run-time you have to do this in `SceneDelegate`